# Raw use of parameterized class 'ABC'

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, suppress-warnings, raw-types

I have the following interface:

```java
public interface AsynchronousJobRunner<T extends AsynchronousJob> extends Runnable {
    public void kill();
    public void addJobExecutionListener(JobExecutionListener listener);
    public void removeJobExecutionListener(JobExecutionListener listener);
    public AsynchronousJobRunner withJob(T job);
}
```

`AsynchronousJob` is an abstract class that can be extended to represent other jobs with a following abstract method:

```java
public abstract class AsynchronousJob implements JSONSerializable, HasId {...}

    /**
     * Returns the class of the {@link AsynchronousJobRunner} that runs this type of job.
     * @return The appropriate class of the job runner for this class.
     */
    public abstract Class<? extends AsynchronousJobRunner> jobRunnerClass();
```

I also have the following `ExportJob` that is extending the base class and has the following signature and method:

```java
public class ExportJobRunner extends BaseJobRunner<ExportJob> { ...}

    @Override
    public Class<? extends AsynchronousJobRunner> jobRunnerClass() {
        return ExportJobRunner.class;
    }
```

Both `jobRunnerClass()` methods have the `Raw use of parameterized class 'AsynchronousJobRunner'`  warning.

The easy solution to make the warning go away are:

```java
public abstract Class<? extends AsynchronousJobRunner<?>> jobRunnerClass();


@Override
public Class<? extends AsynchronousJobRunner<?> jobRunnerClass() {
    return ExportJobRunner.class;
}
```

But what would be the right solution and why/how?

**EDIT**:

I've ended up simply changing the code of the interface to:

```java
public interface AsynchronousJobRunner<T extends AsynchronousJob<T>> extends Runnable {
    void kill();
    void addJobExecutionListener(JobExecutionListener listener);
    void removeJobExecutionListener(JobExecutionListener listener);
    AsynchronousJobRunner<T> withJob(T job);
}
```

Changes to `AsynchronousJob` class:

```java
public abstract class AsynchronousJob<T> implements JSONSerializable, HasId { ...
 /**
     * Returns the class of the {@link AsynchronousJobRunner} that runs this type of job.
     * @return The appropriate class of the job runner for this class.
     */
    public abstract Class<? extends AsynchronousJobRunner<? extends AsynchronousJob<T>> jobRunnerClass();

}
```

`ExportJob` class:

```java
public public class ExportJob extends AsynchronousJob<ExportJob> {...
    @Override
    public Class<? extends AsynchronousJobRunner<? extends AsynchronousJob<ExportJob>>> jobRunnerClass() {
        return ExportJobRunner.class;
    }
}
```

And the `ExportJobRunner` class remained unchanged.

I also forgot to mention that there is some injection magic going on because the jobs are serialized to the database:

```java
    /**
     * Instantiates an {@link AsynchronousJobRunner} instance for the provided job.
     * <p>
     * In order for the creation of the runner to succeed, the {@link AsynchronousJob#jobRunnerClass()}
     * method of the job must specify the appropriate class for its runner.
     *
     * @param job job to create runner for
     * @return job runner configured for the specified {@code job} parameter
     */
    private <T extends AsynchronousJob<T>> AsynchronousJobRunner<T> createJobRunner(T job) {
        return ((AsynchronousJobRunner<T>)injector.getInstance(job.jobRunnerClass())).withJob(job);
    }
```

I've accepted @Andrew Vershinin answer as he got me on the right track of thoughts.

Comment: Where is ABC used as a parameterized class (or anything else for that matter)?

Comment: @NomadMaker, yes, originally, in this case ABC is `AsynchronousJobRunner`. I suppose it would also make sense to parameterize `AsynchronousJob` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you could go with this recursive declaration of `AsynchronousJob`:

```
public abstract class AsynchronousJob<T extends AsynchronousJob<T>> 
    implements JSONSerializable, HasId {

    public abstract Class<? extends AsynchronousJobRunner<T>> jobRunnerClass();
//...
}
```

Don't forget to update `AsynchronousJobRunner` definition accordingly:

```
public interface AsynchronousJobRunner<T extends AsynchronousJob<T>> //...
```

Then, in you job class you can use the class itself in the return type:

```
public class ExportJob extends AsynchronousJob<ExportJob> {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends AsynchronousJobRunner<ExportJob>> jobRunnerClass() {
        return ExportJobRunner.class;
    }
}
```

This way you ensure type consistency: a job of type `T` returns runner types, which run jobs of such type - you cannot ensure this with using `? extends AsynchronousJob` in the `jobRunnerClass` signature, since you could return any runner type and it would compile.

Comment: The solution ended up being slightly different than what you have proposed (and less recursion), but your answer got me on the right track.

Comment: @QuirkyBit What have you ended up with, if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: I've edited the question with the musing that I have came to after reading your answer.

Comment: @QuirkyBit, Yep, this works, but as I mentioned, you don't get compile-time error checking for the runner job type.

Comment: Yes, I probably need to bang my head a bit longer against the code and classes that I need to change. Your answer DID help, thank you again!

Comment: @QuirkyBit Good!

Comment: I think we can go ones recursion less. I have updated the solution that does compile-time error checking (well, at least I think it does).